# How to generate real html of ckeditor output with gatsby static site generator?

Tags: ckeditor, gatsby, strapi, ckeditor5

i have a api backend with strapi and i create all my content with a ckeditor there.
The content should displayed in my gatsby site in real html.
But I query the content with graphql and gatsby show this content only in raw html
Is there a way, to transform the queried content of gatsby to real html?
I couldn't find find any plugin or tool to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a huge lack of trials, source-code, etc. However, what you need to use is the built-in [`dangerouslysetinnerhtml`](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) property. You don't need any plugin at all.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: yourRetreivedData}} />
```

Keep in mind that `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is React’s replacement for using `innerHTML` in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and pass an object with a `__html` key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

Comment: thanks. so you think there is no other option in the frontend? What would your recommendation here, when you want to display content of ckeditor in the frontend.  Is it possible to render this graphql content server side, before generate the pages?

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify to sanitize HTML data for dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Comment: It has issues with the SSR. I've used this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html which is easier to implement